# How allclose() works?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, numpy

What is the difference between relative tolerance (*rtol*) and absolute tolerance (*atol*) in *allclose*. Somebody please explain the meaning of the following.

```
np.allclose(center_var,center_a,rtol=1e-02, atol=1e-03)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are used differently in the formula as you can read [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html):

> If the following equation is element-wise True, then allclose returns True.
>
> absolute(a - b) <= (atol + rtol * absolute(b))
>
> The above equation is not symmetric in a and b, so that allclose(a, b) might be different from allclose(b, a) in some rare cases.