# What is rtol for in numpy's allclose function?

Tags: python, numpy

In `numpy.allclose()` there are two tolerance factors used to determine if two arrays are close enough to count as the same. There is the relative tolerance `rtol` and absolute tolerance `atol`. From [the docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html#numpy.allclose):

```
numpy.allclose(a, b, rtol=1e-05, atol=1e-08)
```

Also from the docs:

> If the following equation is element-wise True, then allclose returns True.
> absolute(a - b) <= (atol + rtol * absolute(b))

Mathematically I understand this, but I am confused about the point of `rtol`. Why not just use a single tolerance value `tol`, and if `|a-b| < tol`, then return `False`? Obviously, following the above equation, I could just do this manually by setting `rtol` to zero, thereby making everything symmetric. What is the point of the symmetry-breaking `rtol` factor?

**Related question**
[How allclose() works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25280690/how-allclose-works)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The confusing part is that the equation shows both parameters being used at the same time. Look at it like this instead:

- **Usecase 1: absolute tolerance (`atol`)**: `absolute(a - b) <= atol`
- **Usecase 2: relative tolerance (`rtol`)**: `absolute(a - b) <= rtol * absolute(b)`

An alternative way to implement both with a single tolerance parameter would be to add a flag that determines if the toerance is relative or absolute. Separating the use-cases like that breaks down in the usecase where array values can be both large and zero. If only one array can have zeros, make that one `a` and use the asymmetrical equation to your benefit without `atol`. If either one can have zeros, simply set `rtol` to some acceptable value for large elements, and set `atol` to the value you want to kick in for zeros.

You generally want to use `rtol`: since the precision of numbers and calculations is very much finite, larger numbers will almost always be less precise than smaller ones, and the difference scales linearly (again, in general). The only time you use `atol` is for numbers that are so close to zero that rounding errors are liable to be larger than the number itself.

Another way to look at it is `atol` compares fixed decimal places, while `rtol` compares significant figures.

Comment: And to add to this excellent answer: Both of these usecases are perfectly legitimate: Either you want to say "I consider two values close if they differ by at most 0.1" or you might want to say "I consider two values close if they differ by at most 0.1%".

Comment: @Lagerbaer. Exactly. It's clear that both needed to be implemented. The manner in which it was done is a bit confusing.

Comment: Case 2 I would understand wanting to scale with the order of magnitude of the data. But then in that case, why would you give precedence to b over a on the right hand side, instead of the mean of a and b (or whatever)? Is this just convention you just pick one and in this case it happens to be b, it could be a coin flip?  [Edit: I guess what bugs me is the asymmetry. :) ]

Comment: @eric. Because you want to know if the elements are close together. If they are far enough that there is a difference beteen, `a`, `b` and `0.5 * (a + b)`, the answer is False anyway.

Comment: @eric. I've updated my answer a bit to talk about where you would want to use both. The general idea is that you normally want to use `rtol`. But you can't for zeros.

Comment: Please note that the default values are `isclose(a, b, rtol=1.e-5, atol=1.e-8, equal_nan=False)`, and the equation shown in the documentation is indeed used in the code (`less_equal(abs(x-y), atol + rtol * abs(y))`). Which means that if you want to use the first usecase, you should set `rtol` to 0. If you want to use the second usecase, you should set `atol` to 0.

Comment: As an example: `np.isclose(3e-10, 1e-10, rtol=1)` is True even though only 100% is allowed by rtol. `np.isclose(3e-10, 1e-10, rtol=1, atol=0)` is False.

Answer (score 6):

Which tolerance(s) to use depends on your problem statement.  For example, what if my array has a wide domain of values, ranging from 1e-10 to 1e10?  A small `atol` would work well for small values, but poorly for large values, and vice-versa for a large `atol`.  But `rtol` is perfect in this case because I can specify that the acceptable delta should scale with each value.